# Chrome API : Reloading current tab with a url using method in Content.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to reload the page with url by scanning content of it. I designed this method in javascript to see if the url has specific stirng in it

Content.Js

```
function init() {
    var d = document.location.href;
    d = toggleDevMode(d);
    return d;
}

function toggleDevMode(url) {
    var hasDevModeOn = '?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1';
    if (url.indexOf(hasDevModeOn) != -1) {
        //toggle 
        url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf(hasDevModeOn));
    } else if (url.indexOf("salesforce.com") == -1) {
        url = url + hasDevModeOn;
    } else {
        url = url;
    }
    return url;

}
```

Functionality I want

I want if user click on icon, it run the script calling method I defined  in content.js onClick Event and checks url.

Based on Logic I defined here, url will be modified.

I want reload the tab with modified url. I tried this piece of code

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
    var newURL = init();
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: newURL
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. Please advice how can I call these method onclick event

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a content script to do this. Discard your `init` function. Put your `toggleDevMode` function together with the following code in a background script. Make sure your manifest specify the `activeTab` permission.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
    var newURL = toggleDevMode(activeTab.url);
    chrome.tabs.update({
        url: newURL
    });
});
```

EDIT: Replace your current `permissions` section from your manifest by the following:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
],
```